# Docker Daemon Connection Error During AWS CodePipeline Deployment

Tags: docker, github, aws-codepipeline, amazon-ecr

I'm currently deploying my application to AWS Elastic Container Registry (ECR) using GitHub and AWS CodePipeline. I've encountered an issue during the build stage where I can successfully build a Docker image locally, but I encounter the following error in CodePipeline:

## **Error: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the Docker daemon running?**

I'd appreciate any insights or solutions to resolve this Docker daemon connectivity problem in the context of my AWS CodePipeline deployment process. Thank you!

i tried sudo docker sudo dockerd and still getting the error